# How to get 6 decimal precision using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

How to get 6 decimal precision using vb.net as in this example (7090982.885183  (6 decimal places precision)) i.e i want to read the .885183 in my previous sample as 6 decimal only.

The javascript for the above looks like :

```
    //declare variables and assign calculated values
var HashA = OrdNo * Amt;
var HashB = MerchID * Amt;
var HashC = MerchID * OrdNo;
var TotalHash = String((HashA + HashB + HashC) / (parseInt(MerchID) + parseInt(RCode)));

//assign only 6 decimal places value
if (TotalHash.indexOf(".") != -1)
    TotalHash = TotalHash.substr(0,TotalHash.indexOf(".")+7);
else
    TotalHash = TotalHash + ".000000";

document.form1.HashCount.value = TotalHash;
```

}

I need to read this no 7090982.8851830000011 as this format 7090982.885183

Comment: What's the type of your input? Can you give sample input and output?

Answer (score 1):

What about using % operater like

you have an variable a and variable decimalresult you should code it like this

```
decimalresult=a % 1000000
```

In this example it should be

```
decimalresult= 7090982.885183 % 1000000
decimalresult = 885183
```

Comment: i used the following code and it worked fine :    Dim HashCount As Decimal = TotalHash.ToString("F6")

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Decimal` and you want to get the value after the decimal dot, you can do

```
result = input - Math.Floor(input)
```